# Locked out of ESXi 6.0 host, but can login to console. How to grant access via ESXCli?

Tags: vmware-esxi

VMware's KB's on this are not helping, I cannot find what I need for my exact situation: **I am locked out of vSphere, but can login locally to the ESXi host at the console (physically, standing at the KVM)** EDIT: I just found out this is called the DCUI. I have enabled SSH and the ESXi shell, but cannot login to either one of them either. What are my options here? I believe what happened is my predecessor setup vCSA 6 on this host (and set vCenter to manage the host itself, thus locking it), but I am not sure since I cannot get into either. Thank you.

Comment: `VMware's KB's on this are not helping` - That statement is kind of meaningless to us. Without knowing which KB's you're referring to we can't possibly hazard a guess as to why they're "not working". It sounds like the host is in lockdown mode. Have you looked at/tried this: https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1008077

Comment: They are just so many KB's, but yeah the host was in Lockdown. I got it figured out.

Comment: If you want to post as an answer I will mark it as the answer, thanks.

Comment: Was the host in lockdown mode? Were you able to resolve the issue?

Comment: Yes, it was just in lockdown mode. I disabled lockdown mode via the DCUI and was able to login. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad to help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the host is in lockdown mode. If so, you'll need to disable lockdown mode. Refer to this article on the procedure:

https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1008077